# Add data to result of FOR XML PATH SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2019

I have a query that produces XML, exactly as I want it:

```
SELECT *
FROM [staging].[vw_mydata] 
FOR XML PATH('DOCUMENT')
```

This code produces this output:

```
<DOCUMENT>
      <BRON>Bulk Import</BRON>
      <INDEXEERDATUM>2015-07-30</INDEXEERDATUM>
      <ITEMVALUE1>ITEMVALUE1</ITEMVALUE1>
      <ITEMVALUE2>ITEMVALUE2</ITEMVALUE2>
      <ITEMVALUE3>ITEMVALUE3</ITEMVALUE3>
      <ITEMVALUE4>ITEMVALUE4</ITEMVALUE4>
      <ITEMVALUE5>ITEMVALUE5</ITEMVALUE5>
      <ITEMVALUE6>2015-07-30</ITEMVALUE6>
      <ITEMVALUE7>ITEMVALUE7</ITEMVALUE7>
      <ITEMVALUE8></ITEMVALUE8>
      <ITEMVALUE9></ITEMVALUE9>
      <ITEMVALUE10></ITEMVALUE10>
      <ITEMVALUE11>ITEMVALUE11</ITEMVALUE11>
</DOCUMENT>
      <BRON>Bulk Import</BRON>
      <INDEXEERDATUM>2015-07-30</INDEXEERDATUM>
      <ITEMVALUE1>ITEMVALUE1</ITEMVALUE1>
      <ITEMVALUE2>ITEMVALUE2</ITEMVALUE2>
      <ITEMVALUE3>ITEMVALUE3</ITEMVALUE3>
      <ITEMVALUE4>ITEMVALUE4</ITEMVALUE4>
      <ITEMVALUE5>ITEMVALUE5</ITEMVALUE5>
      <ITEMVALUE6>2015-07-30</ITEMVALUE6>
      <ITEMVALUE7>ITEMVALUE7</ITEMVALUE7>
      <ITEMVALUE8></ITEMVALUE8>
      <ITEMVALUE9></ITEMVALUE9>
      <ITEMVALUE10></ITEMVALUE10>
      <ITEMVALUE11>ITEMVALUE11</ITEMVALUE11>
</DOCUMENT>
```

However, I need to add information before and after this result.

The following has to preceed the results from the query. This part is fixed and does not change.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DOCUMENTS>
    <VERSION>2.0</VERSION>
    <LICENTIEHOUDER>Henrov</LICENTIEHOUDER>
    <XTN>BulkImport</XTN>
    <ARCHIEFNAAM>Name</ARCHIEFNAAM>
    <ITEMLABEL1>Label1</ITEMLABEL1>
    <ITEMLABEL2>Label2</ITEMLABEL2>
    <ITEMLABEL3>Label3</ITEMLABEL3>
    <ITEMLABEL4>Label4</ITEMLABEL4>
    <ITEMLABEL5>Label5</ITEMLABEL5>
    <ITEMLABEL6>Label6</ITEMLABEL6>
    <ITEMLABEL7>Label7</ITEMLABEL7>
    <ITEMLABEL8>Label8</ITEMLABEL8>
    <ITEMLABEL9>Label9</ITEMLABEL9>
    <ITEMLABEL10>Label0</ITEMLABEL10>
    <ITEMLABEL11>Label1</ITEMLABEL11>
    <ITEMLABEL12>Label2</ITEMLABEL12>
    <ITEMLABEL13>Label3</ITEMLABEL13>
    <ITEMLABEL14>Label4</ITEMLABEL14>
    <ITEMLABEL15>Label5</ITEMLABEL15>
    <ITEMLABEL16>Label6</ITEMLABEL16>
    <ITEMLABEL17>Label7</ITEMLABEL17>`
```

`</DOCUMENTS>` needs to be added to the end so that the whole result looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DOCUMENTS>
<VERSION>2.0</VERSION>
<LICENTIEHOUDER>Henrov</LICENTIEHOUDER>
<XTN>BulkImport</XTN>
<ARCHIEFNAAM>Name</ARCHIEFNAAM>
<ITEMLABEL1>Label1</ITEMLABEL1>
<ITEMLABEL2>Label2</ITEMLABEL2>
<ITEMLABEL3>Label3</ITEMLABEL3>
<ITEMLABEL4>Label4</ITEMLABEL4>
<ITEMLABEL5>Label5</ITEMLABEL5>
<ITEMLABEL6>Label6</ITEMLABEL6>
<ITEMLABEL7>Label7</ITEMLABEL7>
<ITEMLABEL8>Label8</ITEMLABEL8>
<ITEMLABEL9>Label9</ITEMLABEL9>
<ITEMLABEL10>Label0</ITEMLABEL10>
<ITEMLABEL11>Label1</ITEMLABEL11>
<ITEMLABEL12>Label2</ITEMLABEL12>
<ITEMLABEL13>Label3</ITEMLABEL13>
<ITEMLABEL14>Label4</ITEMLABEL14>
<ITEMLABEL15>Label5</ITEMLABEL15>
<ITEMLABEL16>Label6</ITEMLABEL16>
<ITEMLABEL17>Label7</ITEMLABEL17>
<DOCUMENT>
<BRON>Bulk Import</BRON>
<INDEXEERDATUM>2015-07-30</INDEXEERDATUM>
<ITEMVALUE1>ITEMVALUE1</ITEMVALUE1>
<ITEMVALUE2>ITEMVALUE2</ITEMVALUE2>
<ITEMVALUE3>ITEMVALUE3</ITEMVALUE3>
<ITEMVALUE4>ITEMVALUE4</ITEMVALUE4>
<ITEMVALUE5>ITEMVALUE5</ITEMVALUE5>
<ITEMVALUE6>2015-07-30</ITEMVALUE6>
<ITEMVALUE7>ITEMVALUE7</ITEMVALUE7>
<ITEMVALUE8></ITEMVALUE8>
<ITEMVALUE9></ITEMVALUE9>
<ITEMVALUE10></ITEMVALUE10>
<ITEMVALUE11>ITEMVALUE11</ITEMVALUE11>
</DOCUMENT>
<BRON>Bulk Import</BRON>
<INDEXEERDATUM>2015-07-30</INDEXEERDATUM>
<ITEMVALUE1>ITEMVALUE1</ITEMVALUE1>
<ITEMVALUE2>ITEMVALUE2</ITEMVALUE2>
<ITEMVALUE3>ITEMVALUE3</ITEMVALUE3>
<ITEMVALUE4>ITEMVALUE4</ITEMVALUE4>
<ITEMVALUE5>ITEMVALUE5</ITEMVALUE5>
<ITEMVALUE6>2015-07-30</ITEMVALUE6>
<ITEMVALUE7>ITEMVALUE7</ITEMVALUE7>
<ITEMVALUE8></ITEMVALUE8>
<ITEMVALUE9></ITEMVALUE9>
<ITEMVALUE10></ITEMVALUE10>
<ITEMVALUE11>ITEMVALUE11</ITEMVALUE11>
</DOCUMENT>
</DOCUMENTS>
```

This needs to be exported as a XML file.

I tried to do `SELECT 'text in front' + (select for xml) + 'text after'` but that has an unwanted result: all `<` and `>` are replaced with `&lt` en `&gt` effectively destroying my xml.

So basically: how do I add information to the beginning and the end of the result of a `FOR XML` query?

Comment: Show us your *actual* attempt. Seems like you were just missing the `TYPE` keyword based on your statement *"all `<` and `>` are replaced with `&lt` en `&gt`"*.

Comment: I will. I will need to changes some values due to IP but I will show you that

Comment: @Larnu I wasn't paying attention. The `SELECT 'text in front' + (select for xml) + 'text after'` had a FOR XML attached to it which caused the &lt and &gt to appear. Without the FOR XML  works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a sub query for documents. You'll need to use `type` to prevent XML tags escaping.

```
SELECT 
'2.0' AS [VERSION],
'Henrov' AS [LICENTIEHOUDER],
-- Add all other fields.
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [staging].[vw_mydata] 
    FOR XML PATH('DOCUMENT'), type
)
FOR XML PATH('DOCUMENTS')
```